# Check if array of values exist in other array of object data in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this array

```js
const a1 = ["emailuser1@domain.com", "emailuser2@domain.com", "emailuser3@domain.com"];

const b1 = [
    {
        "Name": "username",
        "Email": "emailuser2@domain.com"
    },
    {
        "Name": "username2",
        "Email": "emailuser23@domain.com"
    },
];
```

I want to get all email which does not exist in `b1` and is there in `a1`

without object in array i'm able to check with filter

```js
this.a1.filter(x => !b1.includes(x))
```

Comment: Did you try `this.a1.filter(x => !b1.includes(x.Email))`

Comment: `const b1Set = new Set(b1.map(x => x.Email))` and `a1.filter(x => !b1Set.has(x))`

Comment: @strojan are u sure that works since x doesnt have a property called Email? :)

Comment: MB, you are filtering a1, which is why Email property doesn't exist. You should try @cmgchess 's solution

Comment: actually the filter some solution looks faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const a1 = ["emailuser1@domain.com", "emailuser2@domain.com", "emailuser3@domain.com"];

const b1 = [
    {
        "Name": "username",
        "Email": "emailuser2@domain.com"
    },
    {
        "Name": "username2",
        "Email": "emailuser23@domain.com"
    },
];

const emailsNotInB1 = a1.filter(email => !b1.some(obj => obj.Email === email));

console.log(emailsNotInB1);
```

Comment: please provide some clarification too, question asker with code.

Comment: sure! but from next time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// checks array
const checkEmails = (emails) => {
  return emails.filter(email => !b1.some(obj => obj.Email === email));
}

// call
console.log(checkEmails(a1));
```

hope it helps!